# Using gettext to translate wp-login.php can't translate `Back to` into other language

Tags: login, translation

I created a plugin to translate text of wp-login.php page into Arabic, every thing translated well except `Back to` which appear at the bottom of login form, I can't catch it to translate into Arabic

My site name called Foodonia, and I want to translate `← Back to Foodonia` to `العودة إلى فودنيا` , I tried each one of below:

```
&larr; Back to Foodonia
Back to
Back to Foodonia
← Back to Foodonia
&larr; Back to
```

here is my code

```
function my_custom_login_label( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if (in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) )) { 
        if ($translated_text === 'Username') $translated_text = 'اسم المستخدم';
        if ($translated_text === 'Password') $translated_text = 'كلمة المرور';
        if ($translated_text === '&larr; Back to Foodonia') $translated_text = '&larr; العودة إلى فودنيا';

    return $translated_text;
  }
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_custom_login_label', 20, 3 );
```

My site URL: [http://foodonia.com](http://foodonia.com/)  (changing language between English and Arabic using site nav menu will effect the login language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct string is `'&larr; Back to %s'`. The site name is inserted **after** the translation.

See the function `login_footer()` for details.

Comment: @ toscho Thank you very much, It works. Just I wonder does wordpress consider `%s` as HTML?

Comment: @usamasulaiman The `%s` is a placeholder, which is parsed by [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

Comment: The %s is a "printf format" placeholder for a string. The translation functions let code pass a value (in this case the blog name) which will get put in place of %s.